# Navigation with down to up slide transition turns my transparent system navigation bar to black

Tags: flutter

I have globally set the system navigation bar to transparent in my app.
Using Getx navigation with a down to up animation transforms the system navigation color permanently to black for the app.

This is the method I used :

```
Get.to(
  PageOne(), //next page class
  duration: Duration(seconds: 1), //duration of transitions, default 1 sec
  transition: Transition.leftToRight //transition effect
);
```

I even tried it without the getx navigation and tried Flutter's SlideTransition and I got the same bug.